# 80's Animated movie: An old man joins mission to save a boy stranded on a hostile world

Tags: story-identification, movie

A guy on a space ship picks up a distress call, a boy is stranded on a planet with a hostile environment. He & his crew go to the rescue, stopping on the way to pick up an old man who comes with them. Most of the top of the old guy's skull is metal, from an old injury.

They've various adventures on the way (their ship is boarded by pirates/bandits/hostile forces at one point).

They get to the planet with the boy. They've limited time to save him as the planet is being moved back in time. (I can't remember why) When they find the boy, he's being attacked by giant wasp-type-things.

The boy is injured on the top of his head. The old guy dies protecting him. The boy gets shifted back in time with the planet and - you guessed it - survives, grows up and turns out to be the old guy.

Now that I've remembered some of it, the bits I can't remember are driving me crazy. I'd love to see this again, if I could identify it I might be able to track down a copy.

I'd swear I saw this mid 80's on morning TV, but it I could be out by 5 years either way.
Thanks

Comment: I've seen this, I think. Did the boy communicate with the ship via a microphone, and so refer to the voice as "Mike"?

Comment: @Daniel: Don't remember that particular detail, it could quite well be so.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is the French film [Les Maîtres du temps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Ma%C3%AEtres_du_temps), later dubbed by the BBC as Time Masters.

Comment: That is amazing! I was typing this same question in a very vague way (because I could barely remember the film) into stackexchange and somehow it knew this was a related question and answer :)

Comment: But *why* do you think this is the answer?

Comment: As a kid, I have seen this movie, and somehow it really touched me.  All I could remember is a boy with a metal plate in the skull. This is how I googled it word for word and this is what I found. Amazing find!