# Early 90's scifi cartoon - Boy under a purple dome with a 'mic' and an animal

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It was a bit weird as I remember it - a boy was lost on a planet, was with a pet, looked a bit like a llama, went under a dome shaped thing that looked like purple trees entwined. He had this egg shaped speak with him (think it was red and white) that he called Mic.  I think it was communicating with the ship that was coming to rescue him.  The Llama creature went into a cave and got eaten by tentacles.  I think the boy eventually got rescued, and I also remember something about faceless humanoid things with wings…. Never been able to find or identify it and I would really like to know what it is and if it’s as weird as I remember it…?

Comment: I've answered this one before: duplicate of [80's Animated movie: Old man joins mission to save a boy stranded on hostile world](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31916/80s-animated-movie-old-man-joins-mission-to-save-a-boy-stranded-on-hostile-wor)

Comment: Although, for the sake of avoiding the spoilers in that question if you don't remember it, this is the French film [Les Maîtres du temps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Ma%C3%AEtres_du_temps), later dubbed by the BBC as Time Masters. And yes, it was just as weird as you remember (if not more so).

Comment: @DanielRoseman - The fact that the OP stopped visiting almost immediately after you posted the answer would strongly suggest that you're right