# Unknown VHS sci-fi western-style cartoon movie from the 80s/90s

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, western

I am trying to find a Sci fi cartoon I watched when I was younger but cant remember what its called.

- It had a young blond boy alone on an alien planet
- he grows quick and uses an old space ship he finds on the planet to travel space
- while in space it becomes sort of like a surreal journey. Meaning I remember the ship being pulled apart and put back together
- he finds two people at the end who I believe where his parents but I remember its like they don't know or remember him
- it was a VHS cartoon movie from the mid 80s to 90s. It's animation was western style ie sort of like Scooby doo
- The Phantom Tollbooth is too Disney styled animation.
- it pretty much just focused on the main character the whole time.
- I'm sure that no one actually spoke during the film.

Comment: @matthew Heavy Metal? Or The Phantom Tollbooth?

Comment: I seen _sci-fi western style cartoon_ and I was really hoping it was going to be [Brave Starr](http://www.gstatic.com/tv/thumb/tvbanners/344262/p344262_b_v7_aa.jpg)

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31916/80s-animated-movie-an-old-man-joins-mission-to-save-a-boy-stranded-on-a-hostil

Answer (score 2):

*[Les Maîtres du temps](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Ma%C3%AEtres_du_temps)* aka *Time Masters* from 1982.

[image: Cover image]

> The film centres on a boy, Piel, who is stranded on Perdide, a desert planet where giant killer hornets live. He awaits rescue by the space pilot Jaffar, the exiled prince Matton, his sister Belle and Jaffar's old friend Silbad who are trying to reach Perdide and save Piel before it is too late.

Comment: You should really take [the tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour); we're not really a discussion board here, we're a Q&A site. One of the things we try to do is keep 1 post = 1 question or answer. You've got three posts here, and one answer. What you should really do is edit this and your first post into one, and comment on it with the contents of your third. Taking a skim through [the help center](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) may also help you figure out what we're all about