# Animated film on TV in the 80s: a crane puts a seed in boy's mouth to bring him back to life

Tags: story-identification, animation

I think it might have been early anime. I don't remember more than a few scenes from it, but I remember Chinese dragons chasing wisdom and a crane putting a seed into a boy's mouth to bring him back to life, possibly a lotus seed, I'm not sure.

I am not really sure when this one was from. I remember it being very vividly coloured and quite different from everything else animated at the time.

Comment: The first one is Time Masters, which gets asked about rather a lot ([here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188278/animation-movie-80s-90s-with-brain-sucking-insects), [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31916/80s-animated-movie-an-old-man-joins-mission-to-save-a-boy-stranded-on-a-hostil), [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95267/unknown-vhs-sci-fi-western-style-cartoon-movie-from-the-80s-90s/), etc)