# Looking for a cartoon (or perhaps anime) from the 1980's which aired in Europe (maybe elsewhere)

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

All I remember is that there was a huge structure (not planet-size huge but like a large building), some kind of brain or something similar (neural structure).

Then there was a young boy, IIRC the protagonist, and a recurring older man. Later in the show it turned out that the older man is a version of the young boy from the future.

That's really all I can recall but I distinctly remember that I loved that show and would be insanely happy to rediscover it! Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure you can remember a lot more. How old was the "young boy"? What ethnicity was he? Was he heroic or just hapless? How old was the "old man". What was he wearing? What events occurred in the show? What was the point of this structure? Did it fly or did events just happen near it? Where was the show set, in space or on the ground? When was the show set, in the future or the past?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31916/80s-animated-movie-an-old-man-joins-mission-to-save-a-boy-stranded-on-a-hostil

Answer (score 5):

Alright, based on the information provided, here is what I came up with: [Les Maîtres du temps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Ma%C3%AEtres_du_temps), otherwise known as [Time Masters](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Animation/TimeMasters). A film, rather than a serial cartoon, but it's worth a shot.

It has a child protagonist, Piel, who interacts with an older version of himself. It is also "a 1982 Franco-Hungarian animated science fiction feature film", thus fulfilling the correct time frame and region.

There is actually a large, nearly planet-sized structure - ostensibly a space station, from what I've read. But, given the whole film was, in part, designed by Moebius, cool structures, vehicles, and scenery are very likely to be present. I didn't see anything about a brain or anything to that effect, however.

I hope this helps!

Sources:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Ma%C3%AEtres_du_temps)

[TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Animation/TimeMasters)