# Fantasy Animation from the 80's. Companion pulled into ceiling by tentacles. Other turns around and companion is just 'gone'

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, animation

I have only a few vague memories of this animation, but would like help identifying it:

- From 80's or earlier (watched when I was a child during late 80's or early 90's
- A person (human?) in the animation is travelling with a companion - the companion may be an animal with more than 4 legs (sapient?)? Said companion is lagging behind slightly and gets taken into ceiling by tentacles / taken into trees by vines? When person looks back, the companion is nowhere to be seen and they have to travel on, with no idea where they went. Sad.
- It is likely pure fantasy, as I seem to recall there being strange landscape, flora and fauna but no technology (may be wrong)
- There is death / violence (implicit, possibly explicit) and it was the first animation I saw of this nature, and I remember being shocked and saddened by the above mentioned scene.

That is all I have about the animation but it tugs on my nostalgia gene for some reason. I can say:

- It's not Ghibli
- It's likely not roto-scoped

Comment: same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31916/80s-animated-movie-an-old-man-joins-mission-to-save-a-boy-stranded-on-a-hostil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a perfect match (he does see it happen) but otherwise everything matches a scene from the 1982 Franco-Hungarian animated film [Les Maîtres du temps](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Ma%C3%AEtres_du_temps) - I saw an English dub on UK TV in the mid-1980s called The Masters of Time. I remember the scene clearly and it features in the plot summary on the Wikipedia page:

> traveling with his native companion, Piel has lost his transceiver
>   (and his companion) inside a cave filled with predatory hanging
>   tentacles.

The scene in question is actually available on YouTube: