# Animated film with a boy alone on a planet with a microphone

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

A friend of mine has just asked if I remember an animated film (possibly from the 70s) that featured a young boy stranded on a planet with a microphone that he names Mike.

Comment: This is extremely brief, you might consider asking your friend if he remembers anything else about it that you could [edit] in, see [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) for pointers.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31916/80s-animated-movie-an-old-man-joins-mission-to-save-a-boy-stranded-on-a-hostil

Answer (score 6):

#### [*Time Masters*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084315/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt) (1982) (originally titled: *Les Maîtres du temps*)

> Piel, a little boy, is left marooned on the planet Perdide after both his parents have been killed by giant hornet-like aliens. Thankfully an emergency transmitter provides him with instantaneous communication with Jaffar, an adventurer who was a friend of his father. This Jaffar convinces the current passengers on his ship, an exiled prince and princess, that a rescue mission must be undertaken. Its a long way to Perdide though, so Jaffar first picks up an old technician who knows that planet. Together with two telepathic aliens they start their mission to save Piel, all the time talking to the boy and trying to avoid him walking into danger. But on the way to Perdide, Jaffar and his friends encounter a lot of trouble themselves, including a hive of malignant angels and what seems to be a traitor in their midst

---

I found this by Googling `animated film boy alone planet microphone` which turned up [this other id question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/31916/58193) with the same answer. The answerer also left the following [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31916/80s-animated-movie-an-old-man-joins-mission-to-save-a-boy-stranded-on-a-hostil#comment60466_31916) which led me to check it:

> I've seen this, I think. Did the boy communicate with the ship via a microphone, and so refer to the voice as "Mike"?

Comment: Chailey, if this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.