# Space-themed cartoon film seen on TV in the mid-80's with a pair of blobby telepathic aliens and relativistic aging

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, space

I'm looking for a cartoon space fantasy film that I saw on TV somewhere between 1985-1988. I think it was a one-off and not a series.

I only have sketchy fragments and never got the whole story line, but it involved some form of space travel, quite a few people travelling onboard the vessel, with an old man of some importance who seemed to be comatose. They are trying to save him, I think, and there is some form of relativistic influence occurring, as whatever they are doing, or speed they are travelling at is influencing his age/rate of aging (it might even have been going backward in a parallel dimension).

It was quite an intense, serious cartoon, but nevertheless absorbing. There were also a pair of blobby like sub-characters, pale in colour, with arms and legs who tended to drift about and could pick up the character of thought of those around, and may have been made of thought themselves. They had young child-like voices, somewhere around 8-10 years old or so, with UK-English accents. There was a certain electronic music theme that went with them too. That theme has popped up elsewhere, so I doubt it was scored specifically for this.

It was aired in the daytime, somewhere mid-morning to early afternoon. The old man was white and had a white beard. The other adult characters spoke in English, and had as far as I remember mildly American- or UK- English accents.

Comment: same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31916/80s-animated-movie-an-old-man-joins-mission-to-save-a-boy-stranded-on-a-hostil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this is *[Les Maîtres du temps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Ma%C3%AEtres_du_temps)* (1982), also known as *Time Masters*.

> Les Maîtres du temps (lit. The Masters of Time, a.k.a. Time Masters, Az idő urai in Hungarian) is a 1982 Franco-Hungarian animated science fiction feature film directed by René Laloux and designed by Mœbius. It is based on the 1958 science fiction novel L'Orphelin de Perdide (The Orphan of Perdide) by Stefan Wul.
>
> The film centres on a boy, Piel, who is stranded on Perdide, a desert planet where giant killer hornets live. He awaits rescue by the space pilot Jaffar, the exiled prince Matton, his sister Belle and Jaffar's old friend Silbad who are trying to reach Perdide and save Piel before it is too late.

It contains pretty much everything you described, including a journey through space, a pair of blobby telepathic aliens with childlike voices and British accents, a white-bearded old man in a coma-like state, and some timey wimey stuff going on outside the ship.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I have to say, I am astonished and delighted :) Thankyou very much!